# Unable to Deploy Azure LogicApp with MS teams Connector to different Environment (Testing and Production) - Authorization issue

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I have a simple logic app with **Microsoft Teams connector**, to send message to my Teams channel. This works fine in Development environment as I used my credential in logic app design designer(UI). Now I want to deploy the same logic app to Testing and Production environments and I'm trying to do this via CI/CD with an ARM template. I've exported the Template from Visual Studio but I'm stuck with Team **authorization**. Not sure how I can use different credential with my deployment.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with this.
Note: I've a separate credential to be used in Testing and Production environments (both in the same Subscription)
Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will use [ARM template deployment](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) task to deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template in Azure DevOps, then you could override template parameters in this task.

Comment: yes, That is how I do for all my logic app. But this one has Teams Connector and Im facing issue authorizing the teams when deployed to diff environment

Comment: Does the Team authorization information in ARM template?